# Using a Chrome extension content script to embed additional content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that will add content to a particular set of pages. From my research, it sounds like what I want is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that will execute for the appropriate pages. I can specify the "appropriate pages" using the `content_script.matches` manifest.json field.

However, the problem I'm running into is that content scripts run in an isolated world, [separate from the rest of your extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#contentScripts).

How I had envisioned my extension was a set of [UI pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#pages) that would be embedded on the appropriate pages by the content script. The [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#background_page) would contain the code for build the content of the UI pages. The background page, and by extension, the UI pages, would need access to the various Chrome APIs (e.g., local storage), as well as being able to make cross-domain requests to retrieve their data.  However, it seems this is not possible, since the content scripts run in an isolated world, and don't have access to the Chrome APIs that I need.

[Message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) allows a content script to send and receive data from the background page, but doesn't allow you to take a UI page and embed it on the current webpage.

I initially thought I was making some headway on this when I was able to make a [jQuery AJAX request from my content script for an UI page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315091/can-a-chrome-extension-content-script-make-an-jquery-ajax-request-for-an-html-fi), but that only gets me the HTML file itself. My UI pages depend on code to programmatically build the content--it's not just a static HTML page. And that "build the page" JavaScript code depends on Chrome APIs that are not available to the content script. So, if I just tried to make all my UI pages and JavaScript resources [web_accessible_resources](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), I could inject them into the page but they wouldn't be able to run.

Which brings me to my question: how can a content script pull down, or embed, [UI pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#pages) that can invoke code in the background page?

Answer (score 1):

Tldr: you need to read about sending messages between content/background. Its in the docs and many samples.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to find, the architecture I was hoping for (as outlined in my question) is not possible in a Chrome Extension. Chrome's security model requires a different approach. Here's what worked for me.

- Make your templates, JavaScript files, and anything that's part of your UI,  [web_accessible_resources](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).
- Use your content script to load these resources and display them to the user at the appropriate times/locations.
- ([Almost](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)) any calls to `chrome.*` API need to be done through your [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). In my case, the "background page" is strictly JavaScript, there's no HTML.
- Your content script, and UI, can send [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to your background/event page(s).

This model is not unlike the traditional client/server architecture of a web app.  The "background page" is like your server, and your content script can send "messages" (think HTTP request) to the "background page" just like it might send a request to your server.

The background page, just like the server, has access to resources that the content script does not, e.g., the background page can use more of the [chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html).

This mental analogy helped me to "redesign" my app in a way that (so far) is working within the Chrome Extension security model. I had originally been thinking more along the lines of a traditional desktop app, where the entire app can do things like make cross domain requests or write to the file system. Chrome Extensions and Apps don't work this way, however.

Comment: FYI, content scripts can also make cross-domain requests, use parts of the Chrome API (messaging, storage and some safe extension utilities).

Comment: Background pages cannot make raw TCP requests, so SMTP is not an option either. [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) (**not** extensions) have access to the [`chrome.socket`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket) API, so these could in theory use SMTP to send mail. Chrome extensions cannot write to files in your live filesystem, but if the user has approved the permission, then background pages (not content scripts) can read files. If you want these capabilities, take a look at Chrome Apps. These cannot be integrated in a web page though.

Comment: Well, obviously I've got plenty to learn about all the options here. I updated the answer again.